# Batch script to compare values

Tags: windows, batch, script

```
@echo off
rem  Checks if %~1 is equal to %~2 and returns 1 if true, 0 if false.
rem  DEVS! DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!
if "%~1"=="" goto error
if "%~2"=="" goto error
if "%~1"=="%~2" goto true
if "%~1" neq "%~2" goto false

:error
setlocal
echo error occured
endlocal

:true
setlocal
echo 1
endlocal

:false
setlocal
echo 0
endlocal
```

So, whenever I run this, its supposed to compare if Parameter 1 is equal to Parameter 2. If true, it prints 1, if false it prints 0.

The script seemed to work, it compared 1 and 3 and printed 0 (Meaning it wasn't equal), but when it compared 2 and 2, it printed 1 AND 0 on 2 lines. Its supposed to only print 1, not 1 and 0. I cant find any issues with the code, can anyone else see the problem?

Comment: Why do you think it would not print 0 after printing 1?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams its supposed to only print 1 if its equal, not print 1 and 0, as 0 means not equal. It prints 1 and then prints 0 on something being true if I run it.

Comment: After each `endlocal` add `exit` on the next line beneath those lines or else just use `endlocal & exit` instead and report back your results.

Comment: "Because I think so" is... poor reasoning.

Comment: No problem, the reason is `endlocal` does not stop the logic beneath it from processing so if it goes to `:true` it will also go to the `:false` routine as well unless you `exit` or `goto :eof` at the end of those routines. You really don't need `setlocal` and `endlocal` (https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) in this case from what I can tell so just read up on it and practice your simple scripting logic more and it'll all start making better sense. Also, I like the comment of **"DEVS! DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!"** ... hilarious. You could enforce that with explicit NTFS permissions too though.

Comment: Keep in mind that batch labels do not modify the flow of control the way functions might in other langagues. this is evidenced by the use of `goto`. Consider using the `CALL :labelname` invocation instead of `goto` to get it to return, use `exit` at the end of each function-block, and and exit at the end of your main thread of logic. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_calling_function.htm

Comment: `setlocal` and `endlocal` do not do what you think they do. See [Setlocal - Local variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)